# retrieve fragment with koin

Tags: android, koin

My project has multi modules, and i am using koin. I have HomeActivity which is in `home` module and AskQuestionFragment which is in feature module. I need to show AskQuestionFragment in HomeActivity, so i try to inject fragment with koin.

```
factory (named("askFragment")) { AskQuestionFragment() }
```

then in HomeActivity i write this

```
private val fragmentAsk by inject<Fragment>(named("askFragment"))
override fun onCreate(...) {
    val pagerAdapter = PagerAdapter(fragmentAsk, fragmentOther, fragmentOther2, fragmentBlablabla)
    viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
}
```

It gives me error `Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment' & qualifier:'askFragment'. Check your definitions!`.

For testing purpose, i tried to change

`factory (named("askFragment")) { AskQuestionFragment() }` to be `factory (named("askFragment")) { 74521647256142765412 }`

And it run well, so i think koin is not support fragment injection

How to solve it?

Comment: have you added the module in `startKoin {}` block in your application class modules list?

Comment: yes i did it. all other injection is work fine except the fragment injection

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're trying to inject the subtype "Fragment" but your bean definition is for your class "AskQuestionFragment".

Change your declaration like so:

```
private val fragmentAsk by inject<AskQuestionFragment>(named("askFragment"))
```

Alternatively you can declare your type like so:

```
private val fragmentAsk: AskQuestionFragment by inject(named("askFragment"))
```

Comment: I can't use `AskQuestionFragment` because that it is from other module. That's why i use `Fragment`. Also AskQuestionFragment is extend-ing Fragment(), doesn't it should be ok?